# Load jsf strings in wildfly swarm

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to run a jsf application on wildfly swarm but I'm having some trouble with the resource management. Their short example on [their github](https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/jsf/jsf-shrinkwrap/src) page states :

> You will need to add the xhtml files to Shrinkwrap in a manner such as
>   deployment.addAsWebResource() since JSF is non static.

I didn't manage to make my bundle file recognized. Furthermore I have about 20 .properties file which hold strings. Do I really need to add all of those programatically ?

```
<f:loadBundle basename="strings.strings"> Can't find bundle for base name strings.strings, locale en_US
```

In my main method I have:

```
    deployment.addAsWebResource(
            new ClassLoaderAsset("strings/strings.properties", Main.class.getClassLoader()), "strings.strings");
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSF example you link to uses Shrinkwrap to customize the container and deployment.

If you don't need to customize anything it can pick up the resources automatically as in https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/jsf/jsf-war